# How to delete each element from np. array to get arrays without this appropriate element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy-array

```
   X_test =  [array([1,2]), array([3,4]), array([5,6]), array([7,8]), array([9,10]), array([11,12])]
```

And i would delete each row to get a new arrays:

```
[array([3,4]), array([5,6]), array([7,8]), array([9,10]), array([11,12])]
[array([1,2]), array([5,6]), array([7,8]), array([9,10]), array([11,12])]
[array([1,2]), array([3,4]), array([7,8]), array([9,10]), array([11,12])]
[array([1,2]), array([3,4]), array([5,6]), array([9,10]), array([11,12])]
[array([1,2]), array([3,4]), array([5,6]), array([7,8]), array([11,12])]
[array([1,2]), array([3,4]), array([5,6]), array([7,8]), array([9,10])]
```

I have ever tried get such array through:

```
for i in range(len(X_test)):
    np.delete(X_test, i)
    print X_test
```

Comment: What did you try ? + explicit your question

Comment: btw it looks like you don't have a 2d np.array but a python list of 1d np.array's

Answer (score 0):

```
[X_test[:i] + X_test[i+1:] for i in range(len(X_test))]
```

Gives you a list with the elements you want